# Uknown source of white glare on faces

Tags: faces, reflection

I downloaded a model file from the internet with untextured buildings. The image below shows white glare on the faces of the left building but none on the right building. There are no light sources in the scene, both buildings are in the same viewport and the roof materials are the same for both buildings. I'm guessing it has something to do with the face properties of the building on the left but I don't know what it could be.

Anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Your're in material preview mode which uses a hidden HDRI to provide lighting and reflections. Press Z in the 3D viewport and select "Rendered" from the pie menu to see the lighting as you have set in your scene (in your case no lighting). You can also click the farthest most right of the 4 little circles in the top-right of your viewport (Viewport Shading modes)

Comment: Still there but I found the solution

Comment: Yes, on closer inspection it seems to be smooth shaded as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

```
Object Properties -> Normals -> Auto Smooth
```

this option was unchecked.